# Setting a static IP address to a guest machine if the host also has a static IP

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, ip, virtualization

I have Centos7 VM installed on VirtualBox and it works fine, but when I use the command 
 `ip address` I get the IP as `192.168.0.X`.  The host machine (Windows 10) is on `192.168.100.X` and I need the guest to be on the subnet `100.X`, visible to all its hosts and PCs.

I've searched for a solution and the reason seems to be that the host is configured on a static IP address, I can't change it to DHCP because it's mandatory by my company, but I've acquired a static IP I can use for my machine and I need to set it up, I tried may solutions on the internet but nothing seems to help.

I'm used to setting the adapter as a bridged adapter but I guess this isn't feasible here, what can I do?

I have the interface on Bridged adapter mood and I've never had this issue before with the same appliance when I tried it on a different PC.  I tried installing the machine and VBox many times but without success, what is the issue?

**Edit:** 
 So I played with both Virtualbox's and the VM's configuration, assigning `192.168.100.1/24` to the [VirtualBox adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIPm4.png) ([DHCP server settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElZIw.png))

VM: 
 `eth0`: NAT 
 `eth1`: host only adapter

The VM's IP is changed to `192.168.100.4` and I can ping the VM from the host, but can't ping the host via the VM

Comment: `192.168.100.0/24` really should be avoided, as all cable modems use this subnet, running their web server on `192.168.100.1`.  Have you tried assigning a different IP to that adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do what you want is to set from Host the Guest's adapter to bridge mode so the guest can get IPs from the same network segment as your desired network.
All your guests will then be able to use IPs from your network directly.

If you want not to use your main network's IPs, just put the 2 machines in the same network segment (like 192.168.0.X/24) and make sure you have the correct settings so they communicate with each other.

Comment: Originally I configured the machine on bridged adapter mode as I always do, but it gives the IP as 192.168.0.X

Comment: So what's wrong with that ?

Comment: It's not good for us, we use the VM to access an application using it's IP address, right now it's not visible over the network

Comment: it's only visible on the local host

Comment: As I said, if you want access from main network, bridge them and use main network's IPs. It does not matter if they are static or DHCP as long as they belong to your network's segment.